# SQL Full Text Search is not indexing binary field

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a field in my database which contains a word document. This is stored in a varBinary(max) field.

I use the Full-Text Search to search for text in this field. Herefore I have created a field 'Extension' and every record contains '.doc' in the Extension field. I have set the change tracking to automatic.

Everything works okay, until I create a new record. When I create a new record and I search on a word that is only been put in the new record, the FTS finds nothing. But, when I do this:

`UPDATE table SET Extension = '.doc'`

the FTS finds my new record! How is this possible? What am i missing?

So, when I perform an update on the records, the records are re-indexed?

Comment: Have you tried to just give it some time? If the indexing is done in the background it might not be available immediately after adding the record.

Comment: Yes I've done this. But when I update an existing record with an unique word and I search for this word, I get directly results

Comment: Could you post an EXPLAIN on the query(ies) that search the binary column for some given text?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. Seems it was because the catalog was created and fulltext enabled after the table already had data in it, so the fulltext catalog never updated for the original data. The following served to resolve the problem for my existing data, however there's probably a simpler method:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table SET CHANGE_TRACKING OFF; -- turn auto off
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table STOP POPULATION; -- stop anything in progress
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table START FULL POPULATION; -- do a full population
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table SET CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO; -- auto back on
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but maybe the problem is that you can't full text index a binary/Varbinary column, so you are possibly getting some undefined behavior.

From the [5.1] manual:

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables, and can be
>   created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Although I haven't 'tried' it myself to confirm and re-create your exact situation, where the column seems indexed